# Парсинг текстового документа в Perl

Tags: perl, синтаксический-анализ

Есть текстовый файл следующего содержания:

```
   <br><br><span><a href="javascript:quiz_solution('некоторый текст')"><img 
      src="/images/quiz_solution.png" title="решение задания"></a></span>
</td>
<td><img onclick="img_resize2(this);" 
     style="cursor: pointer;" 
     src="Data/2011/CalcFraction/CalcFraction_163c.gif" 
     align="top">
```

Как отсюда спарсить 'некоторый текст'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $var=qq~
<td><img onclick="img_resize2(this);" style="cursor: pointer;" src="некоторый текст" align="top">
                        <table style="width:100%">
                        <tr valign="top"><td style="width:20px;"></td><td colspan="2"><div>не решено</div></td></tr>
                        <tr valign="top"><td style="width:20px;"></td><td style="width:30px;"></td><td><input name="useranswer12047647" type="text" value="" disabled /></td></tr>
                        </table>
                </td>~;

($var=~/(src="(.+)"\s+align)/mi) && (print $2)
```

Comment: немного изменил текст файла, попутал, извините
посмотрите, пожалуйста

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl

    my $var=qq~ <br><br><span><a href="javascript:quiz_solution('некоторый текст')"><img src="/images/quiz_solution.png" title="решение задания"></a></span>
                    </td>
                    <td><img onclick="img_resize2(this);" style="cursor: pointer;" src="Data/2011/CalcFraction/CalcFraction_163c.gif" align="top">
~;

    ($var=~/(quiz_solution\('(.+)'\))/mi) && (print $2);

    #или так
    if ($var=~/(quiz_solution\('(.+)'\))/mi) { print $2 }

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное

Comment: А вы не могли бы написать, как будут выглядеть регулярки, чтобы вытащить из <img onclick="img_resize2(this);" style="cursor: pointer;" src="некоторый текст" align="top"> некоторый текст?
спасибо ещё раз Вам огромное!

Comment: #!/usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    my $text=qq~<img onclick="img_resize2(this);" style="cursor: pointer;" src="некоторый текст" align="top">~;
    
    if ($text=~/src="(.+)"\s+align="top"/) {print $1}
    #или
    print $1 if ($text=~/src="(.+)"\s+align="top"/);
    #или
    ($text=~/src="(.+)"\s+align="top"/) && (print $1);
    
    # или лаконичней немного
    my $re=qr~src="(.+)"\s+align="top"~; # вынесем регулярку в переменную
    
    if ($text=~$re) {print $1}
    print $1 if ($text=~$re);
   ($text=~$re) && (print $1)

Answer (score 2):

Если текстовый файл содержит только этот кусочек то можно использовать вот такую регулярочку:

```
$someText =~ /src="(.+?)"/;
```

Если в текстовом файле есть еще какие либо "src" то это регулярное выражение работать НЕ будет. Но в приведенном Вами кусочке только один "src"

Answer (score 2):

Парсить html регулярными выражениями, мягко говоря, не рекомендуется. Тем более, что вы с ними не знакомы. Для этого есть другие средства.

На пример, есть хороший парсер в [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us/). В качестве примера его работы рекомендую посмотреть [mojocast/e5](http://mojocasts.com/e5)

PS: Если всё таки нужна регулярка, то достаточно найти все, что находится внутри одинарных кавычек, т.е.: qr/'([^']+)'/

Answer (score 0):

```
use Mojo::DOM;

my $html =<<TEXT;
   <br><br><span><a href="javascript:quiz_solution('некоторый текст')"><img 
      src="/images/quiz_solution.png" title="решение задания"></a></span>
</td>
<td><img onclick="img_resize2(this);" 
     style="cursor: pointer;" 
     src="Data/2011/CalcFraction/CalcFraction_163c.gif" 
     align="top">
TEXT

my $dom   = Mojo::DOM->new($html);
my $img_1 = $dom->find('img')->[0];
print $img_1->attr('title') . ' : '. $img_1->attr('src');

__DATA__

решение задания : /images/quiz_solution.png
```